# Why I can not get remote access to MySQL on Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, remote-access, amazon-rds, pythonanywhere

So, I have already created a new security group `rds_access` for my RDS instance with Inbound-> >Source parameter set to `0.0.0.0/0`, and updated the instance so in the 'Security groups' section on RDS Dashboard I have: *rds_access (sg-xxx)( active )*

In MySQL Workbench "Edit" section of my connection, in the tab "Remote Manager" I have set the value of "Native Windows remote management" radio button to active and "Hostname" parameter to `0.0.0.0`.

The instance and the database connect successfully.

In my web-application running on pythonanywhere I'm still getting this error:

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'bachelor-diploma-db.cx0stetemb8k.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com' ([Errno 111] Connection refused))

Before uploading my app on pythonanywhere, I've tested it on `localhost` and everything was working fine. Also I have rebooted both the RDS instance and MySQL database.

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong and how to fix this issue?

**UPDATE:**
In order to connect to MySQL server I use `flask-mysql`. Here's the code snippet:

```
 from flaskext.mysql import MySQL  
 api = Api(app)

 mysql = MySQL()
 app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'user'
 app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
 app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'bachelor_diploma_db'
 app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'bachelor-diploma-db.cx0stetemb8k.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com'

 mysql.init_app(app)
```

and then in methods I use:

```
conn = mysql.connect()
```

Comment: You might want to show us the Python code you are using to connect to MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you're on a free PythonAnywhere account and free accounts can only connect out on http(s) to a specific whitelist of sites.

Comment: Just read the relevant  PythonAnywhere docs, and I think that's the reason. Thank you.

Comment: @ViktorKonstantinov Can you confirm this solved your problem, in which case I can go ahead and delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the actual publicly visible endpoint for your RDS instance.  `0.0.0.0/0` is just a placeholder meaning any IP address.  From the RDS console, find the details information.  Under "Connect" you should see an endpoint looking something like this:

```
mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

From the command line your connection string would look something like this:

```
mysql -h mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
    -u ec2-user -pPASSWORD yourdb
```

If the above does not resolve the problem, then you may also want to make sure that port 3306 (used by MySQL) is not behind a firewall.

See the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The subnets that the RDS instance is running in also needs to be public ,this can be done by creating a subnet group in rds and adding public subnets to it, took me hours of fiddling to work this one out